# how to use a submit handler which is in an .inc file

Tags: 7, forms

I am adding a submit handler to the drupal commerce submit form:

```
 
module_load_include('inc', 'my_module', 'cim_profile');
$form['buttons']['continue']['#submit'][] = 'my_module_create_cim_profile';
```

The submit handler is located in a .inc file. I assumed that the code above would load the .inc file to be used by the submit, but that doesn't seem to be the case, I keep getting an error that the file isn't found.
When I tested the module include with

```
 $inc = module_load_include('inc', 'my_module', 'cim_profile');
dpm($inc);
```

it did print out the path to the .inc file, so I know it was located.

How can I load my .inc in so that it is available for the submit handler?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want [`form_load_include()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_load_include/7) instead:

> Ensures an include file is loaded whenever the form is processed.
>
> ...
>
> Use this function instead of module_load_include() from inside a form constructor or any form processing logic as it ensures that the include file is loaded whenever the form is processed. In contrast to using module_load_include() directly, form_load_include() makes sure the include file is correctly loaded also if the form is cached.